# When migrating to AutoMapper 4.2/5.0, should I store an IMapper instance or the MapperConfiguration instance in my dependency injection container?

Tags: c#, unity-container, automapper

I am migrating to the [newer configuration](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/) of AutoMapper. I was looking at examples on the [AutoMapper GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration) and am a little confused on how to complete the configuration. The Wiki says in one place you can store the MapperConfiguration instance in your D.I. container (or store it statically), but the next paragraph says you can store the Mapper instance statically. In a nutshell, I am not sure if I should be doing

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>().ReverseMap(); //creates a bi-directional mapping between Foo & Bar
    cfg.AddProfile<FooProfile>(); //suppose FooProfile creates mappings...
});
```

then using a D.I. container such as Unity to store that instance as such...

```
container.RegisterInstance<MapperConfiguration>(config);
```

Where I could later use this instance to perform mappings...

```
public void CreateMapping(MapperConfiguration config, Bar bar)
{
     Foo foo = config.CreateMapper().Map(bar);
     //do stuff with foo
}
```

or, should I be storing the IMapper instance the MapperConfiguration makes

```
container.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(config.CreateMapper());
```

which would have the usage as follows

```
public void CreateMapping(IMapper mapper, Bar bar)
{
     Foo foo = mapper.Map(bar);
     //do stuff with foo
}
```

All I will be doing in my application after the initial configuration is calling the Map method. I will not need to modify the configuration. Should I store the IMapper instance or the MapperConfiguration instance in my dependency injection container?

Update: I ended up with registering IMapper with my D.I. container. In my case, Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't store both. I have cases where I need to inject one or the other or both, as I use `MapperConfiguration` for LINQ projections and `IMapper` for doing the mapping itself. My IoC registrations look like this:

```
public static Container RegisterAutoMapper(this Container container)
{
    var profiles = typeof(AutoMapperRegistry).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t)).Select(t => (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(t));

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    });

    container.RegisterSingleton<MapperConfiguration>(() => config);
    container.RegisterSingleton<IMapper>(() => container.GetInstance<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper());

    return container;
}
```

}

As the `IMapper` object can be created by the `MapperConfiguration`, my IoC is spawning an `IMapper` instance from the current registration of `MapperConfiguration`.

Comment: What version are you using? It depends and from version 4 - to version 5 it has changed. There are some deprecated stuff and there are some new recommendations.

Comment: @alltej could you indicate what are those changes? I'm trying to migrate to version 5.

Comment: @james: Why do you create a new instance of Mapper everytime the IMapper interface is requested? Isn't this an unneeded overhead? It seems to me that a singleton could be better (both faster and lighter in memory)

Comment: A singleton would indeed be more appropriate, I’ll update my answer.