# Automapper configuration setup

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I am using entity framework for my DAL and want to convert entities objects to business objects and vice versa. This is taking place in my BLL project. I am hoping to setup automapper in my BLL project to take... let say Customer.cs auto generated by EF and convert it to CustomerWithDifferentDetail.cs (my business obj)

I attempted to create an AutoMapperBLLConfig.cs under BLL project with the following code:

```
 public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new CustomerProfile());
        });
    }


public class CustomerProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerWithDifferentDetail>();
            cfg.CreateMap<CustomerWithDifferentDetail, Customer>();
        });
    }
}
```

Then I created CustermerService.cs under BLL project with the following code to test if it's working:

```
 public void CustomerToCustomerWithDifferentDetail()
 {
     AutoMapperBLLConfiguration.Configure();
     Customer source = new Customer
        {
            Account = 1234,
            Purchase_Quantity = 100,
            Date = "05/05/2016",
            Total = 500
        };

     Models.CustomerWithDifferentDetail testCustomerDTO = Mapper.Map<Customer, Models.CustomerWithDifferentDetail>(source)
 }
```

I get this Error:
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

I am not sure what I did wrong. I don't have a start_up or global.aspx. This is a class library. I'm not sure what I'm missing or did wrong.

I have a separate project calls Models which hold all the business objects including CustomerWithDifferentDetail.cs. In this case, CustomerWithDifferentDetail only has two properties: Account and Total. If mapped, it should give me Account = 1234 and Total = 500 - basically the same data as entity object just in different shape.

======================= UPDATE=================================
AutoMapperBLLConfig.cs - stay the same as noted above

CustomerProfile.cs

```
public class CustomerProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerWithDifferentDetail>().ReverseMap(); //cut it down to one line with ReverseMap
        });
    }
    CreateMap<Customer, CustomerWithDifferentDetail>().ReverseMap(); //missed this one line before; hence, the error
}
```

CustomerService.cs

```
static CustomerService()
    {
        AutoMapperBLLConfiguration.Configure(); //per @Erik Philips suggestion, move this call to a static constructor 
    }

 public void CustomerToCustomerWithDifferentDetail()
 {
     Customer source = new Customer
        {
            Account = 1234,
            Purchase_Quantity = 100,
            Date = "05/05/2016",
            Total = 500
        };

     Models.CustomerWithDifferentDetail testCustomerDTO = Mapper.Map<Customer, Models.CustomerWithDifferentDetail>(source);
 }
```

Result: my testCustomerDTO returns exactly what I expected.

Comment: You can put .Reverse() after creating the map. No need to do the second "reversed" line.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of that. I am wondering if @James and Erik are referring to that as mapping more than once...

Comment: Just be careful to map specific members correctly when using .ForMember and .Reverse.

Comment: @FernandodeBem What do you mean careful? can you elaborate? I am new to this. Yes, I am using both Reverse and .ForMember. Thanks in advance for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the instance method of AutoMapper:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
  cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerWithDifferentDetail>();
  cfg.CreateMap<CustomerWithDifferentDetail, Customer>();
});
```

Then you need to *use* the instance for mapping:

```
Models.CustomerWithDifferentDetail testCustomerDTO = 
  config.Map<Customer, Models.CustomerWithDifferentDetail>(source)
```

I personally haven't really thought this through in my applications ([I need to move to the instance method instead of the static method](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/)).  ([Migrating from status API](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API)).

*Off the cuff*, based on your code, I'd probably do something like:

```
public class PersonDataObject
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonBusinessObject
{
  private readonly MapperConfiguration _mapper;

  public string Name { get; set; }

  PersonBusinessObject()
  {
    _mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
      cfg.CreateMap<PersonDataObject,PersonBusinessObject>();
    });
  }

  public static PersonBusinessObject MapFrom(PersonDataObject data)
  {
    return _mapper.Map<PersonBusinessObject>(data);
  }
}
```

Then you can simply:

```
PersonDataObject data = new PersonDataObject();

PersonBusinessObject business = PersonBusinessObject.MapFrom(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have a question. How do I access "config" to do config.Map<Customer, Models.CustomerWithDifferentDetail>(source) from CustomerService.cs ? Are you saying that in my CustomerService.cs class, I need to create an instance of the profile? As for the second suggestion. I like how it looks super clean and neat to simply do a PersonBusinessObject.MapFrom(data), but the  mapping would scatter in each of my business object. I have a tons of obj to map. Do you have any suggestion to group them in one place similar to doing the profile?

Comment: Creating maps more than once is not recommended by the author of AutoMapper, it's an expensive process. Rather, store your `IMapper` instance (created from `MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper()`) statically or use dependency injection, as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619635/when-migrating-to-automapper-4-2-5-0-should-i-store-an-imapper-instance-or-the/36691581#36691581

Comment: As @James noted, my code only creates the mapping once using the static constructor.  You could do the same for your CustomerService object I guess.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Thank you. I'm moving my configuration call to a static constructor of my CustomerService class now. I also managed to resolve the error. Turn out I was missing this line: CreateMap<source, destination>().ReverseMap(); I'll update my post in a few minutes. I would love more feedback if you have any. I'm new to this and wanted to implemented it properly.